# 6 Pin USB Type c connector issues

Tags: usb, circuit-design, signal, embedded, hardware

I want to use a Type C connector to send signals from a simple switching circuit. I am totally new to using USB, I ordered a 6 pin female Type c connector. I am not able to find out proper pinouts for the same. I bought it from robu.in. Voltage readings I am getting from the pins after connecting them to the supply are shown below. Need help in identifying the pinouts of this connector and building a circuit for this. If anyone can at least guide me to where to look for the information that will be great!! Thanks in advance!!!!

Link to the product: https://robu.in/product/usb-3-1-type-c-6-pin-for-power-charging-reversible-connector-pack-of-5/

Comment: Contact the seller and ask them to provide a data sheet on the product they have sold you. Otherwise find a more reputable seller who provide the proper information:)

Comment: See [here](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/type-c-in-micro-usb-footprint-(female-connectors)/) for a discussion on this type of connector and a pinout. It might be a power-only connector (as is mentioned in the product description).

Comment: "I want to use a Type C connector to send signals from a simple switching circuit" Using USB for any sort of communications is a complex topic, you'll need to implement some sort of USB device to handle the protocols and a suitable driver on the host. Try and find some sort of ready-made interface instead.